# OuterRef not looking into outer query

Tags: django

I have the following model schema (only putting here the important variables):

```
class Department(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 64)

class User(AbstractUser):
    departments = models.ManyToManyField(Department, related_name = 'users', blank = True)
    date_left = models.DateTimeField(null = True, blank = True)
    ## date_joined = This is set by default on AbstractUser

class Office(models.Model):
    department = models.ForeignKey(Department, related_name = 'offices', on_delete = models.CASCADE)

class Invoice(models.Model):
    office = models.ForeignKey(Office, related_name = 'invoices', on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateField(null = True, blank = True)
    ## nr_workers = The annotation i'm trying to create below
```

And i want to retrieve, for every `Invoice` `date`, the number of active users.

For example,

`invoice.date = '2021-04-01'` -> `nr_workers` should be equal to the number of users from that `invoice.office.department` who joined before `2021-04-01` and, either left after that date, or never left at all.

*What i've tried so far:*

```
from django.db.models import Max, Min, Q, F, Subquery, OuterRef, Value, Count

qs = Invoice.objects.all()
qs = qs.annotate(
    dep_pk = F('office__department__pk')
)
## Works fine until here
qs.annotate(
    nr_workers = Count(
        Subquery(
            User.objects.filter(
                departments__pk__in = [OuterRef('dep_pk')]
            ).filter(
                date_joined__lte = OuterRef('date')
            ).filter(
                Q(date_left__gt = OuterRef('date')) | Q(date_left = None),
            ).values('pk')
        )
    )
)
## Error - "Cannot resolve keyword 'dep_pk' into field. Choices are: ..."
```

The `OuterRef('dep_pk')` is not looking into the `qs` (it's not looking into the Invoices) but it's looking into the `User` queryset somehow..

I've read the documentation about `OuterRef` but still i think i misunderstood how to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is overly complicated for getting a simple count. Anyway a simpler solution is to use [`Count` with filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/aggregation/#filtering-on-annotations):

```
qs = qs.annotate(nr_workers = Count(
        'office__department__users',
        filter=Q(office__department__users__date_joined__lte=F('date'),
               Q(office__department__users__date_left__gt = F('date')) | Q(office__department__users__date_left = None)
        ),
        distinct=True
    )
)
```

Adding [`distinct=True`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.Count.distinct) as an User can be at multiple department(as Abdul Aziz Barkat mentioned in the comments).

Comment: Perhaps also add a `distinct=True` to the `Count`, since a user can be in multiple departments.

Comment: Good idea. I have added to the answer. Thanks

Comment: This gives me the same error: `Cannot resolve keyword 'date_joined' into field. Choices are: (...) ` (shows the choices for `Invoice` instead of `User`).
I fixed the filter parameter to `Q(Q(date_joined__lte = F('date')) & Q(Q(date_left__gt = F('date')) | Q(date_left = None)))` due to syntax error.
My code was definitely too overly complicated! I'm struggling a bit to be honest. Thanks for pointing out the parameters of `Count`. I totally missed that

Comment: date joined and date left are from User model(I missed that). So need to make nested query. I have updated the answer